# Extract the color ID in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using tab20 colormap of matplotlib library and generated ten distinct colors in the following way:

```
cm = plt.get_cmap('tab20')
cy = cycler('color', [cm(1.*i/10)
                      for i in range(10)])
```

If I type `cy[0]` I do not get the first color. I get the error

`"Can only use slices with Cycler.__getitem__"`.

I need to extract the colors based on the indices. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can process like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cm = plt.get_cmap('tab20')
colors = cm(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))

print(colors[0])
```

gives `array([0.12156863, 0.46666667, 0.70588235, 1.        ])`

In case you don't know the numpy module, `np.linspace` helps to create 10 evenly space values between, here, 0 and 1. You could also do:

```
print(cm(0.5))
>>> (0.5490196078431373, 0.33725490196078434, 0.29411764705882354, 1.0)
```

or

```
print(cm(0.3))
>>> (0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392, 1.0)
```

Comment: thank you, how can i use it in plt.scatter, e.g., i want the first color of tab20, how can i write it in here `plt.scatter(......, color=[0])` to get the respective color.

Comment: `plt.scatter(......, color=colors[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Cycler doesn't support get value by index. You can use slicing to get the values in this manner:

```
color_cycle[:1] ##Will output first Color
color_cycle[1:2] ##Will output Second Color
```

For example for `cy = cycler('color', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` the output of `color_cycle[:1]` will be `cycler('color', [1])`